# which position is an absolutely positioned element relative to in its absolutely positioned parent?

Tags: css

which position is an absolutely positioned  element relative to its absolutely positioned parent? parent's border or content?
Css codes:

```
* {
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid darkgray;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top:-20px;
    width: 440px;
    height: 240px;
    background: ;
    border: 5px solid darkgray;
}
```

Html codes:

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Seems the `div with class = "child"` positioned relative to its parent's content, not border, anyone know it exactly position rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to help you understand how positioning works for your case, using some visuals.

Firstly, please keep in mind that you have positioned both elements absolutely and not one relative to the other.

1st check here: http://prntscr.com/e53phe
By making the parent border: 0px you see that the top left pixel of your child, together with its border, is positioned on the top left pixel of your your parent.

2nd, see how it changes when we add border to the parent: http://prntscr.com/e53rcf
The pixels you add as border of the parent are 'taking the space' of the parent's content. So, now the child's top left border pixel is starting where your parent's border 'ends', meaning in the inner corner of your parent's top left.

Hope that helps. I suggest you play with the borders + positioning on your browser to get a better understanding.

PS: I removed the left: -20px;  and top:-20px; attributes to help visualizing

Comment: As a results ,may i say that the conclusion drew the absolutely positioned child relative to content's top left  of its parent  with absolute position